# 2006 Subaru Impreza sedan power window and central Locking stopped working

Tags: subaru, door, power-windows, impreza, central-locking

I replaced my Subaru Impreza sedan doors from my 06 on the drivers side with 05 doors and now all my windows won't work, central locking also isn't working and I've never had a problem before.

I've checked all the fuses and none are blown and I've just found the Power window relay but I'm not sure if that's the problem as the central locking in car won't work now. Can someone tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you check the fuses with a meter as fuses can crack and look good but not work - they don’t have to be blown...

If you don’t have a meter ann AA battery with a small torch bulb is sufficient to test.